Time lag between two audio files is wrong if sample rate is 48000 hz
I have functions that help me find time lag between two audios:
int cross_correlation(float *stream1, float *stream2, size_t num_samples1, size_t num_samples2, float *result)
{
    fftwf_complex *joint_inputs = NULL, *out = NULL;
    float *zero_padded_streams = NULL;
    fftwf_plan forward_plan = NULL, inverse_plan = NULL;

    int ret = 0;

    size_t size = next_power_of_2(num_samples1 + num_samples2 - 1);
    size_t complex_size = (size >> 1) + 1;
    size_t total_input_size = 2 * complex_size;

    joint_inputs = (fftwf_complex *)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * total_input_size);
    out = (fftwf_complex *)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * complex_size);

    if (joint_inputs == NULL || out == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Unable to allocate memory for FFTW-arrays\n", stderr);
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    fftwf_complex *input_1 = joint_inputs;
    fftwf_complex *input_2 = joint_inputs + complex_size;

    zero_padded_streams = (float *)calloc(2 * size, sizeof(float));
    if (zero_padded_streams == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Unable to allocate memory for the streams\n", stderr);
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    float *zero_padded_stream1 = zero_padded_streams;
    float *zero_padded_stream2 = zero_padded_streams + size;

    memcpy(zero_padded_stream1, stream1, num_samples1 * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(zero_padded_stream2, stream2, num_samples2 * sizeof(float));

    forward_plan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(size, zero_padded_stream1, input_1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    if (forward_plan == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Unable to create forward FFT plan\n", stderr);
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    fftwf_execute(forward_plan);

    fftwf_execute_dft_r2c(forward_plan, zero_padded_stream2, input_2);

    array_complex_multiplication(input_1, input_2, complex_size, out);

    inverse_plan = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_1d(size, out, result, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    if (inverse_plan == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Unable to create inverse FFT plan\n", stderr);
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    fftwf_execute(inverse_plan);

    goto cleanup;

cleanup:
    if (forward_plan)
        fftwf_destroy_plan(forward_plan);
    if (inverse_plan)
        fftwf_destroy_plan(inverse_plan);
    if (joint_inputs)
        fftwf_free(joint_inputs);
    if (out)
        fftwf_free(out);
    if (zero_padded_streams)
        free(zero_padded_streams);
    return ret;
}

int audio_delay(size_t num_samples1, size_t num_samples2, float *audio_buffer1, float *audio_buffer2, int *result)
{
    size_t n = next_power_of_2(num_samples1 + num_samples2 - 1);

    float *correlation_result = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);

    if (correlation_result == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Unable to allocate memory for correlation result\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    int return_code = cross_correlation(audio_buffer1, audio_buffer2, num_samples1, num_samples2, correlation_result);
    if (return_code != 0)
    {
        return return_code;
    }

    int ind = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (correlation_result[i] > correlation_result[ind])
            ind = i;
    }

    free(correlation_result);
    *result = ind >= num_samples1 ? ind - n : ind;

    return 0;
}

But if I test these functions in 48000 hz sample rate, I get answer that differs from the right answer (in about 15 ms). What might be the problem in my code? Or should I try using double type to make computations more accurate?
Example: I have two audios: [audio_1] (https://jmp.sh/s/USFPaGnHXVuKFVYarYpm) and [audio_2] (https://jmp.sh/s/jbmWbPTwkdDujAocmi56) - second audio is just a sample of first.  The answer should be 35264 ms, but my function gives 35249 ms

So it works for other sampling rates?

@Jdip as I checked, it gave the right answer in ms, but not sure about samples... maybe the mistake is for all the sample rates, but i'm sure it doesn't work right for 48000 hz
